# Help calculating $\frac d {dx} (1-\cos x)1_{[0,2\pi)}(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I am aware that this could be a very trivial question but actually I haven't found a satisfying answer yet.

Let $x\in \mathbb R$.

How to calculate  $\frac d {dx} (1-\cos x)1_{[0,2\pi)}(x)$?

I guess that it should be something like:

$$\frac d {dx} (1-\cos x)1_{[0,2\pi)}=\sin x 1_{(0,2\pi)}+(1-\cos x)\frac d {dx} 1_{[0,2\pi)}$$

Could think of the derivative of the indicator function as being a (multiple?) Dirac delta concentrated at $\{0,2\pi\}$?

My textbook simply uses $\sin x 1_{(0,2\pi)}$ as the derivative for further calculations (is it because the two are a.e. equivalent?)

Comment: What kind of "derivatives" are you talking about? In the classical sense, $1_{[0,2\pi)}$ is not differentiable at $0$ and $2\pi$. Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: Measures, Integrals and Martingales by Schilling

Comment: The function you mentioned is simply not differentiable at $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$, unless you want to find its [weak derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative), which is another story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) $1_{[0,\,2\pi)}(x)=H(x)-H(x-2\pi)$, if we adopt the regularization $H(0)=1$. Thus in terms of the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), $\frac{d}{dx}1_{[0,\,2\pi)}(x)=\delta(x)-\delta(x-2\pi)$. You can do the rest with the product rule, giving $\color{green}{\sin x\cdot1_{[0,\,2\pi)}(x)}+\color{red}{(1-\cos x)(\delta(x)-\delta(x-2\pi))}$. The red part trivially vanishes if $x\notin\{0,\,2\pi\}$, and if we replace $\delta$ with any nascent delta function these cases aren't exceptional, since $1-\cos0=1-\cos2\pi=0$. So we're left with just the green part, in agreement with @grogTheFrog.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, the derivative is known at all points but at 0 and $2\pi$, so we must use the limit definition there.

For $x_0 \in (0,2 \pi)$, your function is just $1 - cos x$, so that the derivative at $x_0$ is $\sin x\big|_{x_0} = \sin x_0$. On $(-\infty, 0)$ and on $(2 \pi, \infty)$, your function is 0, so that the derivative is 0 there.

For the derivatives at 0 and at $2 \pi$, we must appeal to the limit definition, as the indicator function is not differentiable at its endpoints, so we cannot use the normal derivative rules like product rule. As for your comment about the Dirac delta, this could be valid (I think I've heard a similar interpretation before), but I don't quite see how that would help compute the derivative here.

At $x = 0$, $\lim_{x \to 0-} f(x) = 0$, ($f$ being your function), and $f(0)$ is 0 as well since $\cos 0 = 1$, and we obtain:

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \frac{0}{x} = 0 \, .
\end{equation*}

As we approach from the right, we have

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x -0} = \frac{1 - \cos x}{x} \, .
\end{equation*}

This is the difference quotient for $1 - \cos(x)$ at $x = 0$, so that the value of the (right-hand) limit is equal to the value of the (double-sided) limit from that difference quotient, i.e., $\sin x\Big|_0 = 0$. Since the left-hand limit was 0, the derivative is 0 at $x = 0$.

As for $2\pi$, it is the right-hand limit which is 0, as before, while the left-hand limit is similarly shown to be 0. We thus have

\begin{equation*}
f'(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \notin (0,2\pi) \\ \sin x & x \in (0, 2\pi) \, , \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

which is exactly $\sin x 1_{(0, 2\pi)}$.